# Circuittikz is not drawing a voltage source

Tags: circuitikz

I am trying to draw a circuit. There has to be a voltage source between the small dots, but it does not show up in the circuit.

The following is a minimal example of the problem. I just tried it in Sharelatex.com.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[cuteinductors,american,smartlabels,siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\ctikzset {bipoles/thickness=1}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[ scale =1.4, american, cute inductors, line width=0.8, line cap=round, line join=round]
\draw                          %%%% These commands shoud
(0,2)  [V=20<\volt>] (2,2);   %%%% draw a voltage source
\draw
(0,2)
to [I_=1<\ampere>,*-] ++(0,-2);
\draw (0,0)
to [short] (4,0) to [R=10<\ohm>] (4,2) to [short] (4,4) to [R=10<\ohm>] (0,4) to [short] (0,2);
\draw
(2,2) to [I^=2<\ampere>,*-] (4,2);
\draw
  (2,0)
  to [R=20<\ohm>](2,2);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: The compiled LaTeX code above.]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `to` in line 10:

```
(0,2) to [V=20<\volt>] (2,2);   %%%% draw a voltage source
```